# TS property doesn't exist on type defined by generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type `Columns` that contains information used to render a table:

```
export type Columns = {
  header: React.ReactNode;
  cellContent: <T>(content: T, rowIndex: number) => React.ReactNode;
  ...
}
```

I then define a `Columns[]` array in a component that is going to render some data. You can see an example here:

```
{
  header: 'Site name',
  cellContent: <Equipment,>(equipment: Equipment, rowIndex: number) => {
    return (
      <div className={styles.equipmentNameContainer}>{equipment.title}</div>
    );
  },
},
```

However, I get an error that property 'title' does not exist on type 'Equipment', yet it does as you can see here:

```
export type Equipment = {
  _entity: ResourceType.EQUIPMENT;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  ...
}
```

I noticed that the import of the Equipment type is grayed out in VS Code, and indeed if I delete the import I get no complain about Equipment type not existing, so clearly I am defining something wrong and have somehow created a 'locally scoped type' for Equipment.

What do I need to do to make the content parameter generic and specified by the `cellContent` key when making my columns array?

I have tried googling and have not found anything about this

EDIT: sandbox available here (https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-ibhf7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) that reflects the comment below but still has an issue

Comment: This doesn't quite seem like a [mcve] but it looks like your `cellContent` function is declaring `Equipment` as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type parameter, so it's shadowing the type name `Equipment` from outside.  You don't want to do that.  Perhaps you mean `<T extends Equipment>` and `equipment: T`, but I'm not sure because the example code isn't suitable for me to test in an IDE.

Comment: @jcalz I created something you may view here - https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-ibhf7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark. Sorry, I was trying to stay brief but I could've done that with this from the beginning.

I tried what you suggested and it fixes my shadowing issue, but there is still an error that I haven't figured out how to resolve. Any further guidance would be incredibly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with next ways:

- Directly say TS the T will be Equipment base class. Not the best option, because you loose flexibility.

```
import { Equipment } from "./Equipment";

type Columns = {
  header: string;
  cellContent: <T extends Equipment>(content: T, rowIndex: number) => string;
};

const columns: Columns[] = [
  {
    header: "Site name",
    cellContent: (equipment: Equipment, rowIndex: number) => {
      return equipment.title;
    }
  }
];
```

- Add T as generic to the Type, which is much better from my side:

```
type Columns<T> = {
  header: string;
  cellContent: (content: T, rowIndex: number) => string;
};

const columns: Columns<Equipment>[] = [
  {
    header: "Site name",
    cellContent: (equipment: Equipment, rowIndex: number) => {
      return equipment.title;
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: Ugh, I've been so focused on trying to alter what I have, that I totally failed to step back and realize that I could/should be passing the generic through Columns. Thank you so much!!